# Azure Application Gateway - overide backend path does not seem to do the job

Tags: css, asp.net, azure, azure-application-gateway

I've tried to put an Application Gateway V2 before my website to have some kind of security through the WAF for my website.
The normal way: Listener - Http Setting - Backendpool kind of performs the job perfectly.
However when I try to add my CNAME's to the app gateway I get some issues.

Listener - (multi-site) - cname-website.com
http setting

- overide backend path: /randompath
- overide backend hostname:   Pick host name from backend target
  Backendpool: FQDN of my website (no Azure web app) website.com

As I navigate to my cname-website.com my browser does show me the page of the path.
However some css scripts and pictures are not coming through.
The error messages point out that the browser is trying to navigate to cname-website.com/assets/img/logo.svg. The developers have mentioned that this is normal as these css scripts and images have relative path's and should work with every hostname. But somehow the browser is not showing them.

However when I try to navigate to the backend pool myself website.com/assets/img/logo.svg It seems that the logo can be captured (this is also the case for each css script error).

In some way the overide hostname does not uses the backendpool as the new hostname. But it kind of sticks with the cname-website.com.

Anyone who had this kind of problem or knows what I have done wrong ?

Comment: Why are you overriding the backend path? `cname-website.com/assets/img/logo.svg` is probably trying to hit `website.com/randompath/assets/img/logo.svg`

Comment: because cname-website.com is the cname that has to redirect to the website.com/backendpath.
In the usual flow of the website these cname's are fetched inside code. This has to be done by app gateway from now on.